# How to fix command “python setup.py egg_info” failed?

Tags: python, heroku

When I tried to push on heroku, I get this error:

```
remote:            This backport is for Python 2.7 only.
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7w4exzcs/functools32/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is your Python version because to push on heroku it will be latest version.Check your python version and install latest version 3.6 or 3.7